# Spring Security Reactive OAuth2 Client: Options for Customizing Refresh Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a situation where I'm trying to access a protected resource via OAuth2 Auth Code flow and the authorization server makes refresh tokens available during the initial access token request. The problem arises when trying to make use of these refresh tokens as the authorization server has a distinct refresh endpoint from the token endpoint.

Within a Spring context, that means that this configuration is incomplete:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.test.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8085/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.test.token-uri=http://localhost:8085/oauth/token
```

The missing part is a place where I can defined a "`refresh-uri`".

Upon review of the [OAuth2 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#autoid-57), this use of a distinct refresh endpoint appears to go against the standard. This is clearly why no such "`refresh-uri`" configuration exists in Spring Security. Unfortunately, I have no control over the authorization server I need to interact with so I need to find a method to change the target URI in refresh contexts on the client side.

**Initial Workaround Attempts**

I first consulted [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#_customizing_the_access_token_request_2) for customizing refresh token requests but it appears that the main customization options only allow for modification of parameters and headers.

There is a more freeform approach suggested that allows for using a custom `WebClient` but this also appears to be insufficient as the eventual call to the `WebClient` will make use of the uri defined in the client's provider configuration, as is the case in this class [AbstractWebClientReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/2455feb37947dab10b79b1905be40046257370bb/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/endpoint/AbstractWebClientReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient.java#L124)

This leads into my next thought for a workaround which involves trying to modify the `OAuth2RefreshTokenGrantRequest` in flight to override the client provider configuration token uri value.

Still, I get the sense that I'm missing some sort of obvious approach for something as simple as modifying the target endpoint in refresh contexts. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**Relevant dependency versions:**

- `spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.2.4`
- `spring-boot-starter-security:3.2.4`
- `spring-security-oauth2-client:6.2.3`

Comment: Given that this is very non-standard, I don't think you're missing an "obvious approach" as this scenario isn't really intended. I think whether this is possible might depend on how you're using OAuth2 Client. Can you provide an example of the code that uses it or causes the token endpoint to be called?

Comment: @dur it's a vendor we work with. I tried to convince them their approach was highly unorthodox but they are very resistant to changing it.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Our general scenario is to have the resource owner trigger the auth flow via the frontend where we'll persist the refresh token for offline use. This has me thinking I could create multiple registrations, one for the initial auth and a second one for refresh and let the persistence handle this.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if multiple registrations could work for you. But it depends again on how an access token is getting resolved. For example, the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` probably wouldn't work for you by itself. But if you're doing things more manually, multiple registrations might work.